# I want to add a new index to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a new index to a pandas dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

```
                    date  price  neg_vol  pos_vol
0    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.88       11        4
1    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.89       10        2
2    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.90       16       27
3    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.91        1       10
4    2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.87       12        0
5    2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.88        0       12
6    2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.87        8        0
7    2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.88        0        5
8    2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.87       12        0
9    2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.88        0        8
10   2017-10-17 01:20:00  51.87        6        0
```

Here's the result I want to get:

```
     index                   date  price  neg_vol  pos_vol
0        1    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.88       11        4
1        1    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.89       10        2
2        1    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.90       16       27
3        1    2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.91        1       10
4        2    2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.87       12        0
5        2    2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.88        0       12
6        3    2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.87        8        0
7        3    2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.88        0        5
8        4    2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.87       12        0
9        4    2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.88        0        8
10       5    2017-10-17 01:20:00  51.87        6        0
```

As you can see, index column is set according to date column. If dates of rows are the same, they share the same index number. I think it could be done with some conditional loops, but I wonder if there are more simple ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

- for new column `index`

```
df['index'] = df.groupby('date', sort=False).ngroup() + 1
print (df)
                   date  price  neg_vol  pos_vol  index
0   2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.88       11        4      1
1   2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.89       10        2      1
2   2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.90       16       27      1
3   2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.91        1       10      1
4   2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.87       12        0      2
5   2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.88        0       12      2
6   2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.87        8        0      3
7   2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.88        0        5      3
8   2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.87       12        0      4
9   2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.88        0        8      4
10  2017-10-17 01:20:00  51.87        6        0      5
```

- for new index

```
df.index = df.groupby('date', sort=False).ngroup() + 1
print (df)
                  date  price  neg_vol  pos_vol
1  2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.88       11        4
1  2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.89       10        2
1  2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.90       16       27
1  2017-10-17 01:00:00  51.91        1       10
2  2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.87       12        0
2  2017-10-17 01:05:00  51.88        0       12
3  2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.87        8        0
3  2017-10-17 01:10:00  51.88        0        5
4  2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.87       12        0
4  2017-10-17 01:15:00  51.88        0        8
5  2017-10-17 01:20:00  51.87        6        0
```

Another solution is [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['index'] = pd.factorize(df['date'])[0] + 1
```

---

```
df.index = pd.factorize(df['date'])[0] + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)